# TypeScript - utility in TypeScript 4.7.4 throw TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

Tags: typescript

So I have utility to get nested keys from an object.

```
type NestedKeyOf<ObjectType extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  [Key in keyof ObjectType & (string | number)]: ObjectType[Key] extends Record<
    string,
    unknown
  >
    ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]>}`
    : `${Key}`;
}[keyof ObjectType & (string | number)];
```

In TypeScript 4.3.5 it all works. In TypeScript 4.7.4 I get this error:
[image: error in code]

How I can solve this problem?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBITgEwEJwM4QCyA9phADbIQAekImeyAShAsVJgDx5hSgDmAGmQBXEAGsQxAO4gAfMgDeAWABQyZFAyZiIcgE9kccsHwAuZDz4h%20AbjUatWXQaMiwAC3YBJTBasC9uqa2i6GMMBQPCBwALYQ-ryBDiHOeobAeAAiFBCQfsgARsTE5BggQY6h6cjk%20GAx8YnWdilOOjWxwJiYZY0Jlkk2lakdrgAOxHjAYMC6zcnB7WHI4yKFJngeEJgAgmALw2oAvmpqoJCwiCj7YIge8eAkZJQqwRFlOXgIfOOz84MWiMPhAAMrAABeAxAIlihWgwOAZQAKvpxgMAkd3kiIABVcaYOCQfaHVrBDz4DwAYVIGKGZI07GA-FAxgAYjiAHJxOlAlLjLQAN2AEGkpJGAogwtFHLKuKg5HFKTAaN5i1OqnO4Gg8CQyFBEGIzwoShSZG%20v3%20ICVwVmYDKNo1Z1UFx11zQ2l2PQAopgZsbKDQ6AwPVhcAQA6altVXFhMFo8HgbVU0rGwHcEA8IOAk8hbvdHmAAwBtAC6I2WNUKc34UDg4w8%20mToxWEFicCRzcrrng1C7MYyeAAMqBxAB5EC%20CzFUrlCsD5CZAAK6022wKM7KcAqbQXDd0aqxKbGhgIxAsBqNtPI89Tp5meJE3X7d8s7DAY440AsMLhCJOzpqCq6LIJyEA8DsADSED6GOMCcGOhQAFasGAqIgUG2YhiwbAcNw9LCGIkgyPICgALxRhoxbQRkIDIOIMHEDAyCIShCBoaqyAAGTIAAFJi-DIAAPsgv7wlAACUpYWKxqHoRA1EwaWVC0FhjA4ewXApBoAmCNpogSFIsgpHI%20kAPzIAABgAJIoNHHJZwlWbZ9kAHS2WBEGYDRcEIchcmqop%20ilgomH0IwoAwNAyC4ipwaMAJyAWbFP5StADn6RYNl2TBDlBMcxYMfoTEsf57HydxfGJSJYnQFJQRqDAYjsXMdGQDwyCcMicVqcwrCafhLSEYZJFyAovH9BYnn5D58HInIEmUSEYAiFAdH9ABmqqGwIAdXAyAUe1YCcOgWBepgvr%20teci8QA5Get0Sc6O14LOrnkMQ-C8XAElAA)

Answer (score 1):

Problems like these are common when working with recursive types. My work-around is to store the result of the recursive call in a new generic type which seems to work 99% of the time.

So you can change

```js
`${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]>}`
```

to

```js
`${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]> extends infer U extends string ? U : never}`
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=18&pln=9&pc=101#code/LAKFoFwTwBwUwAQDk4GcJwCYGk5QPIBmAPPgEYBWcAxhACqyJwAeGAdpqggEo0D2AJ0zF0AgJZsA5gBoEAVzYBrNnwDubAHwaEAXgQBvUAgQBtXFAQSEivH0IJyVWg3gIAZAgAUoiZIQAfBDY5AFsyOAEASgBdAC4HShp6RjM8aIQWdk4efiFiI2MEHylpAuMFZTU2Ao0yhAB%20BAADABJ9cwBfJoDmts6AOjaUdCxzIlJE5xTzaO1MuA4uCUIIhABVDNYF7OK-Ro34tjgANwiuuvjW9rwugG5QDpMbKDsEp2TXD28IcSke4LCERi9zAoMgjAQdAADLpkGgMDg8ON9AgAIbxXayMjxFHUDE-XyyTD435%20DodDRAA)

Comment: Error gone, but functionality now broken. I added link to playground with my models. When I write name arg in test function, and use autocomplete - I must get something like this: seo. - seo.title and seo.description

Comment: This seems to be completely unrelated to the issue of the question. The issue here is that `HeadAddEditModel` extends `Record<string, unknown>` -> `keyof HeadAddEditModel` will therefore be `string` which will break the mapped type. So the issue is not really the generic type, but the interface you are passing into it. You should edit the question to have some test cases...